# How to load data into Cloudkit remotely

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have built an app that take advantage of Apple's Cloudkit functionality. What I find difficult is the new clumsy Couldkit UI. It makes it difficult to load a large amount of data or even modify existing records. Is it possible to load data into Cloudkit via other methods? For example is there a way I could load a CSV file of records into Cloudkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seed (and update) a CloudKit container for one of my apps with records from a FileMaker database. My data source is a .tab file rather than .csv, but it works the same. For my project, I have an `Artist` class.

First, add the .csv file to your Xcode project.

Then you need to break that into a return-delimited array of rows with `data.components(separatedBy: "\r")`.

Each row in that array needs to be broken apart with `data.components(separatedBy: ",")`. My source files often contain commas, so I like to break these apart using tab `("\t")` instead.

```
// [Artist]
func makeArtistArray(_ fileName: String) -> [Artist] {

    var array = [Artist]()

    do {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil)
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\r")

        // rows.removeAtIndex(0) // if first row contains field names

        for row in rows {

            let values = row.components(separatedBy: "\t")

            let artist = Artist()

            artist.auctionGroup     = values[0] as CKRecordValue
            artist.auctionNumber    = Int(values[1])
            artist.auctionOrder     = Int(values[2])...

            array.append(artist)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return array
}
```

Then, I pass that array to a function that creates a `[CKRecord]` array and saves everything to my container's public database. If you know your `CKRecordID`'s ahead of time, you can use that to modify existing records. If you pass a non-existing `CKRecordID` (or omit it entirely), you'll create a new record:

```
// [CKRecord]
func makeCloudRecords(_ array: [Artist], recordType: String) {

    var records = [CKRecord]()

    for artist in array {

        let recordID  = CKRecordID(recordName: "\(artist.name!) - Artist")            
        let record    = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: recordID)

        record["auctionGroup"]   = artist.auctionGroup
        record["auctionNumber"]  = artist.auctionNumber as NSNumber?
        record["auctionOrder"]   = artist.auctionOrder as NSNumber?...

        records.append(record)
    }

    // operation
    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    operation.savePolicy = .allKeys

    operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, operationError in

        if let error = operationError {
            // error
        }

        if let saved = savedRecords {
            // print artist.name, or count the array, or whatever..                
        }
    }

    database.add(operation)
}
```

Then, finally, set a button in your app that calls `makeArtistArray()` and pass the result to `makeCloudRecords()`.

Learning how to do this (at the time) took a lot of trial and error, with no official documentation. But I've been using these functions successfully over a year now, regularly, with 2 production apps. Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

*reminder.. the call to `components(separatedBy:)` results in an array of strings, so pay attention to casting non-string values, or your container's record schema won't be happy.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much!